# Safari is forcing HTTPS on everything when I don't want it to

Tags: https, safari

On my localhost development environment, when I manually browse to `http://localhost` it automatically redirects me to `https` every time.

And I get this error:
[image]

When I do the same in chrome, it successfully goes to `http`.

Is there anyway I can mitigate this or to get https to work on my local dev servers? Any help would be greatly appreciated because until I fix it I can't use safari.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I thought it was Cloudflare or my NGINX config but its only Safari.  Chrome and FF work fine.  I tried deleting my HSPT or HPST (can't remember) plist in ~/Library for safari but it didn't have any effect.  I also notice its happening on my phone safari too.  So I don't know if its just the browser or a iCloud synced keychain/access setting.

Comment: update - I went to Cloudflare and added a new subdomain to my host and now it loads right.  so I think something gets stuck in safari.  I wiped my keychain and that didn't do it.  I also deleted all the Safari files and that had no effect.  I'm going to try https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8153691

Comment: The only “solution” I’ve found so far is using `127.0.0.1` instead @mark

Comment: I nuked my web cache/cookies on both my phone and Desktop and I've been ok this last week.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is the same as [this answer for this Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362108/1896) by [@Johnathan Elmore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/86149/johnathan-elmore):

> *HSTS Policy* is now included in Safari's stored website data, and you can remove localhost data to clear this issue.
>
> 1. `command + ,`
> 2. **Privacy** -> **Manage Website Data**...
> 3. Search *localhost*
> 4. Click **Remove**
>
> Change `https://localhost` to `http://localhost` in your address bar and click return key.

The trick here is that, at some point, you visited a `localhost` with an HSTS policy, which means that it will *never* attempt to visit the HTTP version. This is a great security feature for websites generally, but problematic for local development.